# variation of vector field of nonlinear system along the boundary

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-fields, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

For example if I had the 2 dimensional rectangle **R** formed by the vertices $z_1,\ldots,z_4$ and we have a system of linear differential equations $\dot x=f(x)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

If we want that our system evolves inside this rectangle, then the system should not across the facets **F1**,**F2**,**F3**,**F4** of this rectangle, which means the product of normal vector of **Fi** of unit length and
pointing out of **R** with the dynamics of the system  $\dot x$ has the same sign for all points on a facet **Fi** for example $n^Tf(x) \le 0$. For example if we want to verify this condition for every point $x$ on the facet defined by the vertices $z_1$ und $z_2$, it is sufficient to verify this condition : $n^Tf(x) \le 0$ just at the vertices $z_1$ and $z_2$, that is $n^Tf(z_1) \le 0$, $n^Tf(z_2) \le 0$, and not for every $x$ on the facet since we have a linear function $f$.

My question is: in case that the function $f(x)$ is a nonlinear function, why it is not sufficient to verify the above condition just at the vertices to say that is true for every $x$ on the facet?

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you are talking about, even in the linear case. What do you mean by system?

Comment: what i mean by a linear system is a system of linear differential equations : x˙ (t) = f(x(t))

Comment: Ok, look, if you want to get a good answer you should edit your question and add this definition and much more detail, it is really hard to understand now.

Comment: Unclear post. Please provide more context and cite proper references when making certain statements, such as the first one regarding the invariance of the sign. Also, what product are you talking about?

Comment: sorry if I was not clear enough. I edited my question and tried to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider a polytope $P$ with extremal vertices $\{z_1,\ldots,z_N\}$. In such a case, we have that $P=\mathbf{co}\{z_1,\ldots,z_N\}$. In other words, we have that

$$P=\left\{\sum_{i}^N\lambda_iz_i:\lambda\ge0,||\lambda||_1=1\right\}.$$

Let us consider the facet given by the line that connects, for instance, $z_1$ and $z_2$, and consider a vector $v$. If both $v^TAz_1\le0$ and $v^TAz_2\le0$, then we have that $v^TAz\le0$ for all $z\in\mathbf{co}\{z_1,z_2\}$.

In the case of a more general function $f$, we do not necessarily have that $v^Tf(z_1)\le0$ and $v^Tf(z_2)\le0$ imply that $v^Tf(z)\le0$ for all $z\in\mathbf{co}\{z_1,z_2\}$. This will be the case, however, whenever the function $v^Tf$ is convex since we will have that

$$v^Tf(\lambda z_1+(1-\lambda)z_2)\le \lambda v^Tf(z_1)+(1-\lambda)v^Tf(z_2).$$

Therefore, if both $v^Tf(z_1)\le0$ and $v^Tf(z_2)\le0$, then we will have that $v^Tf(z)\le0$ for all $z\in\mathbf{co}\{z_1,z_2\}$.

Comment: thanks for your answer